# Sliding carousel using images in a div with position absolute

Tags: php, jquery

Good evening everyone, I created this code to make a slideshow in which the 3 images will be one above the other in position absolute and left 100% and with display none (The images will have the name "1,2,3" and will have to enter doing a slide from right to left continuously ... So when the slide loads the third image the next one must be the first.
The images will have to scroll automatically through a timer.
I think a solution can be the SetInterval.
I ask for your help in trying to set it up correctly.
I leave you below the code I have set,

Thanks a lot.

```
<div class="section-panel-left">
                <?php
                    $j = 1;
                    for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++){    
                        echo '
                        <div class="mySlides" id=slide_'.$j.'>
                            <img src="'.$j.'.jpg" class="img-full">
                            <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
                        </div>
                        ';
                        $j++;
                    }
                ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You should be able to use the jQuery animate function, https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: ok, but the problem is to make the program understand that once it has done the first it must go on with the second. Could you help me?